# How to prevent WordPress.org from overriding Git Updater for new versions?

Tags: wordpress, git, github

Like many developers who use WordPress, I grew tired over the years dealing with WordPress.org for my open source themes and plugins, and began using GitHub to host all my releases, which eventually lead me to [Git Updater](https://github.com/afragen/git-updater).

Because of namespace conflicts, if a theme or plugin that I release on GitHub has the same directory (folder) name as another one from WordPress.org, Git Updater can't "see" new versions, because WordPress.org takes priority over GitHub.

[I came across a way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/disable-update-notification-for-individual-plugins) to disable WordPress.org update checks, but this also affects Git Updater negatively. How can I release themes or plugins using whatever directory name I want, without conflicting with WordPress.org?

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing a [few](https://github.com/afragen/git-updater/issues/746) [other](https://github.com/afragen/git-updater/issues/581) [previous](https://github.com/afragen/git-updater/issues/893) [issues](https://github.com/afragen/git-updater/issues/876) that other developers had opened recently with similar conflicts, I discovered a snippet that you can add to your themes or plugins hosted on GitHub that will solve this issue:

```
add_filter(
    'gu_override_dot_org',
    function ( $overrides ) {
        return array_merge(
            $overrides,
            array( 'plugin-folder/main-script.php' )
        );
    }
);
```

Edit: revised snippet as per this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/afragen/git-updater/issues/1019).

It doesn't show up well in search engines, but the related documention is found here:

https://git-updater.com/knowledge-base/wordpress-org-directory/

Note: I also tried the new `Update URI: false` header as suggested, but it didn't work and I suspect it conflicts for the same reason as the link in my OP question above. To be honest, this new header seems [rather pointless](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/introducing-update-uri-plugin-header-in-wordpress-5-8/), since third-party updates aren't supported...